# How can I view the total number of registered users on my log file (webapp is ROR using Devise)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I built a webapp using Ruby on Rails and devise for user authentication and setup.

I just want to be able to do two things: 1) see the list of registered users (emails) that have signed up and 2) count the number of registered users.

How can I extract this information from my log files using my terminal?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to use a log file for this? It's in the database.

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to get a quick look into who just signed up while on my terminal.  I'm new to rails so where do I find this info in the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the database/using the console: locally:

```
rails c
```

if you are on Heroku:

```
heroku run console
```

Then inside the console:

```
User.all.map(&:email) # returns all emails

User.count # returns the number of users
```

If you do this too often, you may want to create a small dashboard inside the application itself, accessible only to an admin user.

Answer (score 2):

For rails 4 instead of using map you can:

```
emails = User.pluck(:email)
```

and for count emails without querying the database:

```
emails.size
```